# How to change Graphviz subgraph rank?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want subgraph clusterCG to have same rank as 3 (clusterCG schould not contain 3)

```
digraph G{
 rankdir = LR;
 node [shape = none]

 1->2->3->4[arrowhead=none]

 node [shape = ellipse]

 A->A2->A3;

 subgraph clusterCG{
  shape = rect;
  rank=same;
  A2;
  B;
  C;
  color=blue;
  label="C";
 }

 { rank=same; 1; A;}
 { rank=same; 3; CG;}
 { rank=same; 4; A3;}
}
```

[image]

CG is generated as independent node with rank 3.

I want the subgraph clusterCG to have rank 3.

Comment: FDSg, shouldn't you accept the answer.  It looks good to me!  I know you wrote it yourself, but it was quite helpful.

Comment: I agree.  This helped me figure out a difficult problem I was having in a different kind of layout.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but it seems that zero size nodes is the only thing that works

```
digraph G{
 rankdir = LR;
 node [shape = none]

1->2->3->4[arrowhead=none]

node [shape = ellipse]
ACG[shape = none,label="",width=0, height=0];

CG->A2 [style=invis,constraint=false];

A->ACG[arrowhead=none];
ACG->A2->A3;

 subgraph clusterCG{
  shape = rect;
  rank=same;
  A2;
  B;
  C;
  color=blue;
  label="C";
 }

 { rank=same; 1; A;}
 { rank=same; 2; ACG;}
 { rank=same; 4; A3;}

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

use different rank algorithm with "newrank=true"

```
 digraph G {
 newrank=true
 rankdir = LR;
 node [shape = none]

 1->2->3->4[arrowhead=none]

 node [shape = ellipse]

 A->A2->A3;

 subgraph clusterCG{
  shape = rect;
  rank=same;

  A2;
  B;
  C;
  color=blue;
  label="C";
 }

 { rank=same; 1; A;}
 { rank=same; 3; A2}
 { rank=same; 4; A3;}
}
```